# How do I filter SQLAlchemy results based on a columns' value?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to serialize results from a SQLAlchemy query. I'm new to the ORM so I'm not sure how to filter a result set after I've retrieved it. The result set looks like this, if I were to flatten the objects:

> A1  B1  V1
>
> A1  B1  V2
>
> A2  B2  V3

I need to serialize these into a list of objects, 1 per unique value for A, each with a list of the V values. I.E.:

Object1:

- A: A1
- B: B1
- V: {V1, V2}

Object2:

- A: A2
- B: B2
- V: {V3}

Is there a way to iterate through all unique values on a given column, but with the ability to return a list of values from the other columns?

Answer (score 0):

Yup just use `func.array_agg` and `group_by`

```
import sqlalchemy.sql.functions as func
session.query(Object.col1, Object.col2, func.array_agg(Object.col3))
     .group_by(Object.col1)
     .group_by(Object.col2)
     .all()
```

But this will only work with database back ends with an equivalent aggregation functions, apart from that you are just going to have to write your own group by pseudo function. Sql alchemy merely just translates your pythony code to the appropriate sql, all other logic is usually left up to the programmer.

Equivalent Postgresql

```
SELECT col1, col2, array_agg(col3)
FROM objects
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use association tables and the joinedload() function. The documentation is a bit wonky but I got there after playing with it for a while.